# Find html and css from an element that is only displayed in a autocomplete list when hovered

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, autocomplete, firebug

I am working on a new site, and I am new to CSS/HTML, I learned about firebug etc and it is very useful to monitor stuff etc. However I got an issue with finding what is happening to an item that is on an autocomplete list, the problem is that the item dissapears once I click on firebug and I can t see what it is.

I have been searching for a couple of hours but can t find the proper thing that is happening to the list (is it javascript ? is it a new css class that gets added by javascript? I can t find it out!)

Here is the url so you can see my problem: solved

At the top bar there is a search field. if you type a letter it will show a list of objects that got the letter, however if you hover over the item, you ll see that the layout gets messed up(and this is the issue I am trying to fix)

Any help with how I could find out how to debug or what the problem might be would be great.

Comment: Is the problem that an item is disappearing, or that the layout is getting messed up?

Comment: Right click and select inspect element !!

Comment: the problem is that there is like a top and bottom margin when you mouseover it(so layout getting messed up). And I can t find the source of what is causing it(because I want to remove it then)

Comment: when I right click and select inspect element, then the list dissapears (it doesn t realy) but the hover gets away, so it doesn t work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a ul with the id **ui-id-1** at the bottom of the page. Find it with Firebug and remove the display: none;. Then you type in a letter so the list appears. Now you can right-click the listitems for debug purposes.

Answer (score 1):

I have run into this before and been forced to add inline styles `display: block` to otherwise hidden elements, so i could debug the relevant CSS.

Of course you'll want to remove that after you fix the issue.

Comment: add "display: block" to ".completechamplist_item_container" and then reupload?

Comment: Yes, or add it through firebug to the HTML element itself (right-click element in HTML inspector and click 'New Attribute' then add `style="display:block"`

Answer (score 1):

Firebug (or really any browsers inspector tools, apart from IE) allow you to fake the various states (hover, focus, active), In firebug there's a little dotted rectangle in the top right corner, click that an it shows you the states, simply inspect the element you want to apply the state to and check the box. It's possible you'll need to apply a hover to more than one item to debug.

Comment: the problem is that when I try this that the list dissapears ? and once I try to get the items again it generates new items?

Comment: Where is this _little dotted rectangle_ you speak of?

Comment: Sorry, I've actually looked now, the problem is two things, the display:none style applied to #ui-id-1 and the ui-state-focus class that gets added to the anchor <a> element, you can turn off the display:none and just type/paste that class into the a's class attribute, then you'll be able to debug and see that the problem with the style is the border that gets added to the various classes: .ui-state-hover, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-hover, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-hover, .ui-state-focus, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-focus, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-focus {
border: 1px solid #999;

Comment: also that dotted rectangle is chrome's inspector, my bad, Firebug has them under something else but I don't have firebug on this machine